# How to manage third-party Nagios/Icinga plugins?

Tags: linux, debian, nagios, package-management, icinga

What is the recommended way to manage installed Nagios (or Icinga) plugins?

At the moment all plugins on my system are installed from Debian/Ubuntu packages, so this takes care of updates, file integrity and clean deinstallation. Is there a similar way to manage plugins which are provided e.g. on http://exchange.nagios.org?

My current impression is that I have to manually download the script files from the website and place them e.g. somewhere in /usr/local/. But I have to manually check for updates and bugfixes to these scripts, I have to manually keep track of where these files were downloaded from, and I have to manually keep track of dependencies in case a plugin consists of multiple files.

Is there a better way to manage such plugins?

Comment: I wished there was a good way to do this, version tracking is hard. Sometimes only parts of the scripts are updated. Usually watching repos on Github is a good idea, but something like a pkg management, not that easy.

Comment: You would think that such a thing would be a benefit of having paid support?